# Fortran - How to write user-defined I/O for an array of different classes with the same parent?

Tags: class, serialization, fortran, polymorphism, fortran2008

I need to implement a function, which will serialize (i.e. save to an unformatted binary file) a class containing an array of objects, which belong to the same abstract class, but which belong to several different inherited classes.

The point is, that this array is passed to my function and it's created by user's actions. So, I have no way of knowing about the specific types being stored in the array.

Is there any way to implement write and read I/O methods in a way, which would automatically write the array without having to specify types of its single elements?

I have written this code to illustrate my situation:

```
module m
    implicit none

    type :: container
        class(a), allocatable :: item
    end type container

    type, abstract :: a
        integer, public :: num
    contains
        procedure :: write_impl => write_a
        procedure :: read_impl => read_a

        generic            :: write(unformatted) => write_impl
        generic            :: read(unformatted)  => read_impl
    end type a

    type, extends(a) :: b
        integer, public :: num2
    contains
        procedure :: write_impl => write_b
        procedure :: read_impl => read_b
   end type b

    type, extends(a) :: c
    end type c

contains

    subroutine write_a(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(a), intent(in)    :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        write(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num
    end subroutine write_a

    subroutine read_a(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(a), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        read(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num
    end subroutine read_a

    subroutine write_b(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(b), intent(in)    :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        write(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num, this%num2
    end subroutine write_b

    subroutine read_b(this, unit, iostat, iomsg)
        class(b), intent(inout) :: this
        integer, intent(in)         :: unit
        integer, intent(out)        :: iostat
        character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

        read(unit, iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) this%num, this%num2
    end subroutine read_b
end module m

program mwe
    use m

    implicit none

    class(a), allocatable :: o1, o2, o3
    class(container), allocatable :: arr(:)
    integer :: i

    o1 = b(1,2)
    o2 = c(3)

    allocate(arr(2))
    arr(1) = container(o1)
    arr(2) = container(o2)


    ! How to serialize 'arr' without specifying its elements' types?

end program mwe
```

So, is there any way, how to serialize such an array without having to manually specify, that `o1` is of type `b` and `o2` is of type `c`?

I need to be able to serialize an array of the abstract type `a` in general and also read it from the binary file without previous knowledge about its elements.

Comment: I don't know which part is causing you trouble.  Is it simply whether you can do `write(unit) arr` and then see `o1` have it's defined output followed by `o2` having its?

Comment: When reading from a unit: how could the program know which type on the hyerarchy it should try to read? In other words, how can generic resolution be done without knowing the type of the record?